# How to init a Rust vector with a generator function?

Tags: rust

Hopping between languages can be painful. Idioms of one language "feel good" and one starts to look for the same idioms in other languages.

In F#, there is a way to init an array with the help of a generator function. [`Array.init n generator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.init%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D). Now, that I hopped to Rust for a little while, I wonder if there is a similar facility in place or if I have to create myself such a facility.

Studying [Rust standard library documentation about vectors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), I could not find anything similar to what I am looking for.

```
// Looking for something similar to:
Vec<T>::init(n : usize, generator : F) -> Vec<T> 
    where F: Fn(usize) -> T {
    // ...
}
```

Maybe it works differently in Rust, by means of iterators. But I must admit, that Rust iterators (and their myriads of flavors) are still a tad foggy to my simple mind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a `range` withing a `map` and then collect the results.

Like in the example for `F#` docs:

```
let my_vector : Vec<i32> = (1..11).map(|x| x*x).collect();
```

Check this [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0eda12fbd5325ed764dbcc0e3618ba51&version=stable)

Answer (score 11):

Pretty late to this party, but: [`resize_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with)

Comment: Nice, seems more canonical than `collect()`ing.

Answer (score 7):

Though @Netwave provides the answer, I'd point to a solution which uses it and provides both more reusability and readability.

1. Define a generic function, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d12e75d8a1e0c1c32739dcef246476a1&version=stable):

   ```
   fn initialize<T>(count: usize, f: fn(usize) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
       (0..count).map(f).collect()
   }

   fn main() {
       let my_vector = initialize(10, |i| i as i32);
       for e in my_vector {
            println!("{}", e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define a trait, implement it for whatever you want and use it, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=552a938c7cd8aca1c3a5154fcd100354&version=stable):

   ```
   trait Initializer<T> {
       fn initialize(count: usize, f: fn(usize) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
           (0..count).map(f).collect()
       }
   }

   impl<T> Initializer<T> for Vec<T> {}

   fn main() {
       let my_vector = Vec::initialize(10, |i| i as i32);
       for e in my_vector {
           println!("{}", e);
       }
   }
   ```

   or [more general way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7a2efe4ada32662ae986f92c11997591&version=stable):

   ```
   trait Initializer<T, U> {
       fn initialize(count: usize, f: fn(usize) -> U) -> T;
   }

   impl<T: std::iter::FromIterator<U>, U> Initializer<T, U> for T {
       fn initialize(count: usize, f: fn(usize) -> U) -> T {
           (0..count).map(f).collect::<T>()
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       let my_vector = Vec::initialize(10, |i| i as i32);
       for e in my_vector {
           println!("{}", e);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Write a macro, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3be8e2f25336a77e2bcc39050d1f5a9d&version=stable):

   ```
   macro_rules! vec_init {
       ($count: expr, $f: expr) => { (0..$count).map($f).collect() }
   }

   fn main() {
       let my_vector: Vec<i32> = vec_init!(10, |i| i as i32);
   }
   ```

The base still the same is in the @Netwave's answer. You've asked that you want something like:

```
// Looking for something similar to:
Vec<T>::init(n : usize, generator : F) -> Vec<T> 
    where F: Fn(usize) -> T {
    // ...
}
```

And there is exactly this code in the second item.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way (since Rust 1.51.0): [`fill_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.fill_with).

But [`resize_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with) (see answer by @Listerone) is probably better in most cases, since `resize_with` lets you start with an empty vector, while for `fill_with` the vector already has to have to desired length.