# Fill a vector of struct elements by iteration rather than using .push() one by one

Tags: vector, rust

I am trying to find an elegant way to fill a vector of struct elements with a loop or logic instead of writing one `.push()` for every element I create.

The `struct` element is a question with many more fields than in the following example and the instances need to be mutable because they are modified by user input :

```rust
struct Question {
    id: usize,
    question: String,
}

fn main() {
    //A large and growing list of questions
    let mut q0 = Question {
        id: 0,
        question: String::from("A field I fill in manually"),
    };
    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
    let mut q100 = Question {
        id: 100,
        question: String::from("Another field, each one is different"),
    };

    let total_questions: usize = 100;

    let mut w: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for a in 0..total_questions {
        let s = format!("q{}", a);
        w.push(s);
    }
    //w contains ["q0", "q1", ..., "q100"] but is of type std::string::String

    let mut v: Vec<&mut Question> = Vec::new();
    //Expects type struct `main::Question`

    //I would like to avoid :
    v.push(&mut q0);
    v.push(&mut q1);
    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
    v.push(&mut q100);
}
```

I am not sure that in my example the `w: Vec<String>` is of any use.

I have looked into `.collect()` but could not understand how to utilize it in my case.

I'd be happy to be pointed towards a similar question if this is a duplicate I have not found one.

Edit : I have changed the structs string content as it was misleading. They each contain Strings that are unique and cannot be generated. I also realized that Stack Overflow automatically included this in a `some_fn()` function when we are actually inside `main()`

Comment: How your `Question` structs are produced ?

Comment: Is it important that `v` be a `Vec<&mut Question>` with references to local variables? Why not just `Vec<Question>`?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to init a Rust vector with a generator function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48021408/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Is something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51b8c9eea25b603a18347691a4c05745) what you're looking for?

Comment: @ÖmerErden my `Question` structs are hardcoded into the program. They contain a question and multiple possible answers and a field that takes a user's answer. They cannot be created by a function. My example (over)simplified how they look since they contain longer strings than things like `"Q1"`

@trentcl The structs are hardcoded inside the main loop which is why `v` is a vector of references to the questions. Your example program works but I oversimplified my sample code for comprehension's sake. Image each question has up to 8 String fields filled with blobs of text unique to each.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for pointing towards that post. Using a range might be a solution but I don't understand how. To be more specific on my problem, I have to create each `Question` struct myself inside the program because they contain many String fields that only I can fill in. However, the number of structs in the program may vary over time and I'm trying to find a way to store in a variable the total number of structs so that i only have to use that variable as an iterator cap to always load the `v` vector without having to paste `.push(&mut q###)` lines

Comment: I don't understand why you say you need `Vec<&mut Question>`. This complicates things because *some*thing has to own the `Question`s. What's wrong with just `Vec<Question>`?

Comment: Thank you @trentcl you are right. Since all the structs are hardcoded in the program I can include that inside the creation of a `Vec<Question>` instead of creating mutable structs and then pushing references of them in a Vec<&mut Question>. This eliminates my problem altogether. Sorry I didn't see that the first time you commented it. I have tested it and it seems to work in a simplified version of my program. If if works on the full version I will mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: Maybe you should focus on creating `Question` structs without hardcoding. You can use json format(load external JSON file or embed as JSON string) then deserialize as `Vec<Question>`. If you still want to write as hardcoded then you can create your struct with a constructor, you can push the question while it constructs like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc5c3dee3c92ae87dcc11a3418966e84)

Comment: I wrote an answer based on my suggestion so you can accept it if it did answer your question. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you don't have any data structure that contains the `Question`s -- you just have 100+ independent local variables -- it's not possible to iterate over them to fill the `Vec`. You can fix this by putting all the `Question`s in a `Vec<Question>` as you create them. Here's an example:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<Question> = vec![
    Question {
        id: 0,
        question: String::from("Q0"),
    },
    // ...
    Question {
        id: 100,
        question: String::from("Q100"),
    },
];
```

In fact, once you do this you probably don't need the `Vec<&mut Question>` at all, since you can mutate the questions directly by indexing `v`. However, if you do need the vector of references for some reason, you can create it by collecting an iterator:

```rust
let v_refs: Vec<&mut Question> = v.iter_mut().collect();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate your `Question` object with a function you can use an iterator. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f41c1628e45355ef63689610a347009a) is an example which just generates numbered `Question` objects out of a numeric range:

```rust
struct Question {
    id: usize,
    question: String,
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Question> = (0..10)
        .map(|x| Question {
            id: x,
            question: "Q".to_string() + &x.to_string(),
        })
        .collect();

    for x in &v {
        println!("{}: {}", x.id, x.question);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b11d46cf08521f8f13024477bbf0c86) is an example where you get the strings from an array of strings:

```rust
struct Question<'a> {
    id: usize,
    question: &'a str,
}

const QUESTIONS: [&str; 3] = ["A", "B", "C"];

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Question> = (0..questions.len())
        .map(|x| Question {
            id: x,
            question: questions[x],
        })
        .collect();

    for x in &v {
        println!("{}: {}", x.id, x.question);
    }
}
```